# C socket programming - Read and Write of TCP Server and Client out of sync

Tags: c, sockets, server, client

I have a simple server and client in C.

The steps of the functionality I want to achieve is:

1. The server sends a character "%" to the client and it gets printed on the client's screen.
2. The client then types in a message that would be sent to the server and printed on the server's screen, saying "Client: (message from client)".
3. The server finally sends a message that says "Message received" to the client and it would be printed on the client's screen.
4. Return to step 1.

I've added an indicator called **valid** for the client to tell the server when the buffer (message from client) is actually valid to prevent the **client write** and **server read** from being out of sync.

However, what I got as a result was something like this:

[image]

Thank you in advance !

Code for client:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

void error(const char *msg){
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);  //terminate program
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){   
    
    int sockfd/*(file descriptor)*/, portno, n;
    char buffer[255];
    int valid = 0;
    
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    
    
    portno = 1234;
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd < 0){
        error("Error opening socket.");
    }
    
    
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(1234);
    if( connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0 ){
        error("Connection failed");
    }
    
    
S:  bzero(buffer, 255);
    n = read(sockfd, buffer, 255);
    if(n < 0){
        error("Error reading from socket");
    }
    printf("%s", buffer);

    bzero(buffer, 255);
    fgets(buffer, 255, stdin);
    
    // valid is set to 1 and sent to server 
    // when the message in buffer is actually typed in and meant to be sent to the server 
    valid = 1;
    write(sockfd, &valid, sizeof(valid));
    write(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    if(strncmp("exit", buffer, 4) == 0){
        goto Q;
    }

    bzero(buffer, 255);
    n = read(sockfd, buffer, 255);
    if(n < 0){
        error("Error reading from socket");
    }
    printf("%s", buffer);
    goto S;
    
Q:  printf("You have chosen to exit. Exit successful\n");
    close(sockfd);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Code for server:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

void error(const char *msg){
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);  //terminate program
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    
    int sockfd/*(file descriptor)*/, newsockfd, portno, n;
    char buffer[255];
    int valid = 0;

    int count = 0;
    
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
    socklen_t clilen;
    
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd < 0){
        error("Error opening socket.");
    }
    
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
    
    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(1234);
    
    if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0){
        error("Building failed");
    }
    
    listen(sockfd, 5); //integer stands for max clients
    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
    
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
    
    if(newsockfd < 0){
        error("Error on accept");
    }
    
    int num1, num2, ans, choice;
    
S:  
    valid = 0;
    bzero(buffer, 255);
    if(count == 0){
        count++;
        strcpy(buffer, "********************************\n** Welcome to the BBS server. **\n********************************\n%");
    }else{
        strcpy(buffer, "% ");
    }
    n = write(newsockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    if(n < 0){
        error("Error writing to socket");
    }
    
M:
    // check if the message from client (buffer) is valid
    read(newsockfd, &valid, sizeof(int));
    // if not, return to M
    if(valid == 0){
        goto M;
    }
    // continue if valid
    bzero(buffer, 255);
    read(newsockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    if(strncmp("exit", buffer, 4) == 0){
        goto Q;
    }
    printf("Client: %s\n", buffer);
    

    bzero(buffer, 255);
    strcpy(buffer, "Message received.\n");
    n = write(newsockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
    if(n < 0){
        error("Error writing to socket\n");
    }
    goto S;
    
    
Q:  close(newsockfd);
    close(sockfd);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `fflush(stdout);` after `printf()`. Output is line-buffered, so you wno't see anything if it doesn't end with newline.

Comment: You have `Command received` in the screenshots, but I don't see that in the code. So this isn't the same code that produced that output.

Comment: I just edited to update the correct photo, thanks for reminding.

Comment: Do not construct loops with `goto` statements.  There are a couple of reasonable use cases for `goto`, but they are uncommon, and loops are not one of them.  Use `for`, `while` and `do ... while` statements instead, with `break` and / or `continue` where necessary.  Sometimes factoring your code into multiple functions helps, too.

Comment: I tried using fflush(stdout) as you suggested, but 3 "Clients:" still appear on the server after a single write from the client, and 2 "Message received" appear on the client.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, I'll try to modify it to a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has numerous issues, but the one that is causing the particular misbehavior you ask about comes from this code in the server:

> ```
>     bzero(buffer, 255);
>     read(newsockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer));
> ```

The buffer having just been zeroed, you can be confident that `strlen(buffer)` will return 0.  The `read()` therefore does not actually transfer any bytes.  You probably wanted `sizeof` instead of `strlen`:

```
    bzero(buffer, 255);
    read(newsockfd, buffer, sizeof(buffer));
```

Other issues immediately evident in the code include

- An assumption that the each side's `write()` calls will pair up one-to-one with the other side's `read()` calls to transfer complete messages.  You are using a stream socket, so in fact there are no message boundaries. It is common to see a `read` receive bytes from multiple `write`s, and sometimes the bytes from one `write` will split across two or even more `read`s.  Thus,

  - If you want to exchange data in units of complete messages, then you need to layer something on top of the stream that enables the participants to recognize the message boundaries.
  - Each side must be prepared to receive partial messages.
  - Your transfer of the `valid` signal value is in no way sufficient to ensure that client and server remain in sync.
- Calls to `read` and `write` are not guaranteed to transfer the full number of bytes specified.  If you want to transfer a specific number of bytes then you must use the return values of these functions to determine whether you actually did so, and if not, how many more bytes need to be transferred.
- Client and server receive up to the full size of the buffer at each `read`, and they assume that the buffer contents can thereafter be handled as a string.  However, if one `read` in fact reads the maximum number of bytes (and there are no embedded null bytes) then the buffer will not be terminated, and the assumption that its contents can be treated as a string will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the issue regarding strlen and sizeof. I will also figure out how to use the read and write functions correctly.